# Gsutil - How can I check if a file exists in a GCS bucket (a sub-directory) using Gsutil

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a GCS bucket containing some files in the path

gs://main-bucket/sub-directory-bucket/object1.gz

I would like to programmatically check if the sub-directory bucket contains one specific file. I would like to do this using gsutil.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 14):

If your script allows for non-zero exit codes, then:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path=gs://main-bucket/sub-directory-bucket/object1.gz
gsutil -q stat $file_path
status=$?

if [[ $status == 0 ]]; then
  echo "File exists"
else
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

But if your script is set to fail on error, then you can't use exit codes. Here is an alternative solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'exit' ERR

file_path=gs://main-bucket/sub-directory-bucket/object1.gz
result=$(gsutil -q stat $file_path || echo 1)
if [[ $result != 1 ]]; then
  echo "File exists"
else
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it explains the case of exit codes as well.

Comment: Instead of setting a trap, you could use something like `if [ "$(gsutil -q stat $file_path ; echo $?)" = 0 ]`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [gsutil stat](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat) command.

Comment: Thank you jterrace. I did check out gsutil stat - especially the gsutil -q stat option. It looks perfect for my use case. However, Google says that we can only use gsutil -q stat on objects within the main directory. That is, it will not work for objects contained within sub-directories. Is there any other way to check if a object within a sub-directory exists? Thanks!

Comment: Subdirectories don't really exist. Please see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

Comment: @activelearner - it's talking specifically about directories themselves, not the objects inside, e.g. `gsutil stat gs://bucket/dir/subdir/foo.txt` would work fine. I'll file a bug about updating the docs to make it more clear.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [gsutil stat](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat) command. For accessing the  sub-directories with more number of files use wildcards(*).

For example:

```
gsutil -q stat gs://some-bucket/some-subdir/*; echo $?
```

In your case:

```
gsutil -q stat gs://main-bucket/sub-directory-bucket/*; echo $?
```

Result *0* means *exists*; *1* means *not exists*

Answer (score 3):

There is also `gsutil ls` (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls)

e.g.

```
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

Output is either that same filepath or "`CommandException: One or more URLs matched no objects.`"

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the **ls** command and counting the number of rows of the output.

If 0 then file not there, if 1 the file exists.

```
file_exists=$(gsutil ls gs://my_bucket/object1.gz | wc -l)
```

The same could be used for many files of course.

```
files_number=$(gsutil ls gs://my_bucket/object* | wc -l)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30012551)

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you want to do something depending on the result of that listing (if there are for example parquet files on a directory load a bq table):

`gsutil  -q stat  gs://dir/*.parquet; if [ $? == 0 ]; then  bq load ... ; fi`